Yarn Install fail in Dockerfile when using proxy
I've got this build that fails everytime we try to install Yarn, thus I tried to use Yarn set proxy but still without success.
I tried this since am forced to use a proxy with my self-hosted agent:
RUN yarn config set proxy http://proxy:port
RUN yarn config set https-proxy http://proxy:port
RUN yarn install
RUN yarn build
It fails with this error :
#31 [frankenphp_prod 12/18] RUN yarn config set proxy http *****
#31 0.526 Internal Error: Error when performing the request to https://registry.npmjs.org/yarn; for troubleshooting help, see https://github.com/nodejs/corepack#troubleshooting
#31 0.526     at fetch (/usr/lib/node_modules/corepack/dist/lib/corepack.cjs:22882:11)
#31 0.526     at async fetchAsJson (/usr/lib/node_modules/corepack/dist/lib/corepack.cjs:22896:20)
#31 0.526     at async fetchLatestStableVersion (/usr/lib/node_modules/corepack/dist/lib/corepack.cjs:22948:20)
#31 0.526     at async fetchLatestStableVersion2 (/usr/lib/node_modules/corepack/dist/lib/corepack.cjs:22971:14)
#31 0.526     at async Engine.getDefaultVersion (/usr/lib/node_modules/corepack/dist/lib/corepack.cjs:23349:25)
#31 0.526     at async executePackageManagerRequest (/usr/lib/node_modules/corepack/dist/lib/corepack.cjs:24207:28)
#31 0.526     at async BinaryCommand.validateAndExecute (/usr/lib/node_modules/corepack/dist/lib/corepack.cjs:21173:22)
#31 0.526     at async _Cli.run (/usr/lib/node_modules/corepack/dist/lib/corepack.cjs:22148:18)
#31 0.526     at async Object.runMain (/usr/lib/node_modules/corepack/dist/lib/corepack.cjs:24279:12)
btw am using Azure devops pipeline with Self-hosted agent to build my project.
Iv'e tried different method but still stack with this error
Thanks in advance for your help
